# Linux Bash Script - match lower case path in argument with actual filesystem path

Tags: linux, bash, sh, case-sensitive

I have a linux script that gets an argument passed to it that originates from MSDOS (actually DOSEMU running MS DOS 6.22).  The argument that gets passed is case insensitive (as DOS didn't do cases) but of course Linux does.

I am trying to get from the following passed argument

```
/media/zigg4/vol1/database/scan/stalbans/docprint/wp23452.wpd
```

to

```
/media/zigg4/vol1/Database/SCAN/STALBANS/DOCPRINT/Wp23452.WPD
```

I do not know the actual case sensitive path so I need to somehow determine it from the argument that is passed to the script.  I have absolutely no idea where to start with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

**edited for extra information and clarity**

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer by @anubhava I used the following:-

```
#!/bin/bash

copies=1
if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
  copies=$2
fi

find / -readable -ipath $1 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied" | while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    lpr -o Collate=True -#$copies -sP $FILE
done
```

Works great :-)

Comment: Convert both paths to lowercase and then compare

Comment: @anubhava thanks for your comment.  Maybe I wasn't clear in my question.  I don't actually know the second path.  that is what I am trying to find based on the argument passed to the script

Comment: So now this script will be running under linux or DOS?

Comment: Linux - the background is I am trying to implement network printing in DOS :-)  I have created a batch file that takes a filename as an argument.  This dos batch files does some logic and creates a Linux path which is great but not case correct.  I pass that variable into my Linux script and then will use lpr to print to a network printer of the users choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-ipath` option of `find` for ignore case path matching:

```
# assuming $arg contains path argument supplied
find . -ipath "*$arg*"
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @l0ckm4 : Interesting to note that find provides a handful of options for case insensitive matching like `iname, ipath, iregex` and so on. gnu find manpage suggests to use `-iwholename` instead of `-ipath`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if [ "$( echo $real | tr A-Z a-z )" = "$lower" ]; then 
    echo "matchy"
else
    echo "no is matchy"
fi
```

Some notes:

1. `tr` is doing a to-lower translate.
2. The `$( ... )` bit is placing the result of the enclosed command into a string.
3. You could do the translate on either side if you aren't sure if your "lower case" string can be trusted...

Comment: Hi Dan,  Thanks for the answer.  I am not sure if this is what I need though. The first line implies (to me anyway) that I know two variables; $real and $lower.  I actually only know the $lower ie the argument passed to the script.  It is the $real that I am trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

I would employ `awk` for this (of course without salary)

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -varg="$1" -vactual="/media/zigg4/vol1/Database/SCAN/STALBANS/DOCPRINT/Wp23452.WPD" 'BEGIN{
if (tolower(arg)==tolower(actual)){
printf "Argument matches actual filepath\n"
}
}'
```

Run the script as

```
./script "/media/zigg4/vol1/database/scan/stalbans/docprint/wp23452.wpd"
```

Comment: Hi sjsam,  Thank you for your answer.  It seems my original question was not clear so I apologise for wasting your time.  I do not know the real path only a case insensitive version of it.  it is the case sensitive version I am trying to obtain.